# behat + selenium grid with MinkExtension

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, behat

I'm using Behat, mink and selenium2 for integration testing and writing my tests on my VM (linux) and want to fire up firefox (from a Windows machine) to test Ajaxified functionalities. so, I run two selenium server (node and hub), they can talk to each other and when I run my test on Linux the firefox opened, but the url not appearing on the browser and I get the following error:

> exception 'WebDriver\Exception\UnknownError' with message 'Error forwarding the new session new session request for webdriver should contain a location header with the session.' in vendor/instaclick/php-webdriver/lib/WebDriver/Exception.php:157

I'm using selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar on Windows machine (NODE) and selenium-server-standalone-2.28.0.jar on my VM (HUB)

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Cheers,
Orod

Comment: any updates on this one ?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the same issue, but I had to set the browser version capability to an empty string in order for the hub to choose a node (see http://zalas.eu/running-behat-in-parallel-with-selenium-grid/).

Comment: Does it work if you run both client and hub on the same linux machine? Maybe the problem is not in the inter-system communication and driver version difference but some problem of the underlying code being used?